# Windows Phone 7 - WebBrowserTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Can I show the WebBrowserTask In internal web Browser control?

Comment: If it works as WebBrowserTask, then it will work in hosted WebBrowser control. Use Browser.Navigate(Uri), also set Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true; http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae35ca/working-with-web-browser-control-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WebBrowserTask` is used for launching the Windows Phone web browser at a specified URL. It is a C# class, so you cannot use it from JavaScript embedded within a `WebBrowser` control. You can however send a notification from your JavaScript code (see [this blog post](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/11/windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control-script-notify/)) to the C# app that hosts it, which can then launch the `WebBrowserTask`.

Comment: I want to show a chart on a link http://t1beta.deustechnology.com/FinancialLounge/finance.html?codDT=AC1B0053493D5A7CCAC0 in the web browser control, n m not able to show it.

Comment: and also i want to show a pdf in WebBrowser, im not able to do the both.